# Unable to export connection

Tags: node.js, json

I'm creating a skill that will do stuff on Salesforce platform. I'm using [Jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/) library to do it.

Here is the case.

I've 2 files

1. index.js
2. restServices.js

I wanted to separate my rest endpoint actions into the second file, leaving index with only the responses after processing the request. I did account linking and it is working fine. Using below code I am establishing connection(post oAuth authentication on Alexa app) as explained [here](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#access-token). and here is my code.

```
function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, response) {
    if (!session.user.accessToken) {
        response.speechText = "Hi there, to experience the best of our service, request you to link your account. please click on, Link Account in your alexa app";
        response.isAccountLinking = "true";
        response.shouldEndSession = true;
        response.done();
    } else {
        var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
            instanceUrl: process.env.INSTANCE_URL,
            accessToken: session.user.accessToken
        });
        conn.identity(function (err, res) {
            session.attributes.loggedInUser = res;
            if (err) { return console.error(err); }
            console.log("user ID: " + res.user_id);
            console.log("organization ID: " + res.organization_id);
            console.log("username: " + res.username);
            console.log("display name: " + res.display_name);
            response.speechText = `Hi ${res.display_name}, How can I help you today?`;
            response.repromptText = 'How can I help you today?';
            response.shouldEndSession = false;
            response.done();
        });
    }
}
```

This is working fine and giving the exact result as expected. Now I wanted to use this established session variable and pass to my restServices file, so that, I don't end up making unnecessary calls.

the way I'm doing it is before `conn.identity` block, I'm making a session variable as

session.attributes.conn = conn;

And I get error as

> {    "errorType": "Error",    "errorMessage": "Unable to stringify
>   response body",    "stack": [        "Error: Unable to stringify
>   response body",        "    at _trySerializeResponse
>   (/var/runtime/RAPIDClient.js:166:11)",        "    at
>   RAPIDClient._post (/var/runtime/RAPIDClient.js:127:22)",        "
>   at RAPIDClient.postInvocationResponse
>   (/var/runtime/RAPIDClient.js:39:10)",        "    at complete
>   (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:34:12)",        "    at done
>   (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:59:7)",        "    at succeed
>   (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:63:5)",        "    at Object.succeed
>   (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16)",        "    at
>   Response.done (/var/task/index.js:79:23)",        "    at
>   /var/task/index.js:200:22",        "    at
>   /var/task/node_modules/jsforce/lib/promise.js:72:9"    ] }

Thought some issue with stringify and changed this line to

session.attributes.conn = JSON.stringify(conn);

Now, I get the below error.

> {    "errorType": "TypeError",    "errorMessage": "Converting circular
>   structure to JSON",    "stack": [        "TypeError: Converting
>   circular structure to JSON",        "    at JSON.stringify
>   ()",        "    at /var/task/index.js:198:44",        "
>   at /var/task/node_modules/jsforce/lib/promise.js:72:9",        "    at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)"    ] }

This is very confusing, unable to understand where am I going wrong. Please let me know on how to fix it.

And also I want to know on how I can send this conn to my restServices file

Thanks

Comment: Pretty old already, but for everyone stumbling over this, here is a post on a similar problem, maybe it helps, he even links back to this question: https://dev.to/dvddpl/alone-against-a-bug-1hjo